# I want to print values of a variable in an array in php

Tags: php

i want to print the values of variables in an array but nothing appears, can someone help ?

```
<?php

$i = 0;
$array = array();
function addInArray($var, $array) {
    $array[] = $var;
}
while ($i < 10) {
    ${"char" . $i} = 1;
    addInArray(${"char" . $i}, $array);
    foreach ($array as $values) {
        echo $values.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $i++;
}

?>
```

Comment: Your `$array` var inside `addInArray` is a copy of the one you pass as parameter. See [Passing by Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Comment: Why do you need a function for that? And if you do for some reason, why not just use `array_push`?

Comment: Looks like some form of exercise code as `${"char" . $i} = 1;` just seems like a useless way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answers, i just used array_push and it worked well, in fact i'm not sure i'm doing this the right way but i'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Reference: What is variable scope, which variables are accessible from where and what are "undefined variable" errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and?r=SearchResults&s=2|123.8644). 
 You either need to pass by reference `&`:

```
$i = 0;
$array = array();
function addInArray($var, &$array) { //HERE
    $array[] = $var;
}

while ($i < 10) {
    ${"char" . $i} = 1;
    addInArray(${"char" . $i}, $array);
    foreach ($array as $values) {
        echo $values.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Or `return` the array from the function:

```
$i = 0;
$array = array();
function addInArray($var, $array) {
    $array[] = $var;
    return $array;  //HERE
}

while ($i < 10) {
    ${"char" . $i} = 1;
    $array = addInArray(${"char" . $i}, $array); ??HERE
    foreach ($array as $values) {
        echo $values.PHP_EOL;
    }
    $i++;
}
```